# d3 JS Dynamic Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, d3.js

I'm trying to draw a chart onto an HTML5 canvas via d3.js.

I'm following an example on how to do it from here:
http://bocoup.com/weblog/d3js-and-canvas/

I've defined the following in my `onLoad` function:

```
 var jsonData = [1, 5, 6, 7, 9, 3, 10];

// add a Canvas element to our chart element
// choosing canvas so we can have animations should we decide to
var canvasElement = d3.select("#chart")
    .append("canvas")
    .attr("width", 800)
    .attr("height", 575);


// virtual container for our circles
var inMem =document.createElement("customCircle"); 
var circleContainer = d3.select(inMem);


// make the circles for each of the categories
makeCircles(jsonData, circleContainer);
drawCircles(canvasElement, circleContainer);
});
```

And the `makeCircles` and `drawCircles` are defined as follows:

```
function makeCircles(data, circleContainer) {
var databind =circleContainer.selectAll("customCircle.circle")
                              .data(data);
databind.enter()
    .append("customCircle")
    .classed("circle", true)
    .attr("x", (Math.random() * 800))
    .attr("y", function(d) { return d; })
    .attr("fillStyle", "#5cb85c");
```

}

```
function drawCircles(element, dataContainer) {
console.log(dataContainer);
var graphicsContext = element.node().getContext("2d");
graphicsContext.fillStyle = "#fff";
graphicsContext.rect(0, 0, 800, 575);
graphicsContext.fill();

var elements = dataContainer.selectAll("customCircle.circle");
elements.each(function(d) {
    var node = d3.select(this);
    graphicsContext.beginPath();
    graphicsContext.fillStyle = node.attr("fillStyle");
    graphicsContext.arc(node.attr("x"), node.attr("y"), node.attr("size"), 0, (2 * Math.PI));
    graphicsContext.fill();
    graphicsContext.closePath();
});
```

I can't seem to get anything to show up in the actual canvas itself though, it's just empty. I'm suspecting the `dataContainer.selectAll("customCircle.circle")` line as my code never enters the each loop (and hence never draws). I can't figure out why it wouldn't though; all the custom elements exist when I check it via `console.log`.

Here's the accompanying JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/37871qu4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple things:

```
 dataContainer.selectAll("customCircle.circle");
```

would select all the children of customCircle **that are customCircle** with a class of .circle.

I think you meant:

```
dataContainer.selectAll(".circle");
```

Which is all the children of customCircle that have a class of .circle.

Next,

```
node.attr("size")
```

You never assign "size" to your nodes.

Finally,

```
.attr("x", (Math.random() * 800))
```

Gives all nodes the same x value.  Try:

```
.attr("x", function(d,i){ return Math.random() * 800; })
```

Fixed up [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/37871qu4/2/).

Comment: Thanks a lot! You were correct, my "size" attribute wasn't assigned, so everything set to zero.